# compare two numbers in c using char and strcmp

Tags: c

I am trying to compare two set of data using `strcmp`. This first set of data are `var1` which is get from `fgets(var1, 100, stdin)`. The second set of data are generate randomly by `rand`. When I complie it, I get two same errors. They both come from `char f`.

> warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast `printf(f);`
>
> warning:assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast    `if (strcmp(var1,f)==0)`

i already declare the randomly generated number `char f = rand() % 38;` in char, why will it not work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>  
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char var1[100];
    int result; 
         
    fgets(var1, 100, stdin);          
    srand(time(NULL));
     
    char myArray[38] = { 1,5,3,4};
    char f = rand() % 38;
    
    printf(var1);         
    printf(f);        
    
    if (strcmp(var1,f)==0) {
        result = 1;
        printf("It work\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("It didn't work!\n");
        result = 0;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

**EDITED CODE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>  
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char var1[100];
    int result; 

    scanf("%s",var1);          
    srand(time(NULL));

    char myArray[7] = { 0,28,9,26,30,11,7 };
   int randomindex= 1 + (rand() % 100);
 char f = myArray[randomindex];
   char str_f[2] = { f, '\0' };
        printf("var1: %s\n",var1);
   printf("%s",str_f);
   
   printf("\n");
    if (strcmp(var1,str_f)==0) {
        result = 1;
        printf("It work\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("It didn't work!\n");
        result = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first parameter to `printf` must be `char*`, not `char`. Same with `strcmp`. And by the way, what you call "datasets" is called "strings".

Comment: Which book are you reading? The reason I ask is that people who have these kinds of problems are often reading an atrocious book, or not reading a book at all. Would you like a recommendation? How might you find one, using the "search" feature of this website?

Comment: if (strcmp(var1,f)==0) Check it out. Is it valid or not? check the formal argument and what you did.

Answer (score 1):

As commented above, in **C Langage**, functions from Library have a strict format and using not that expected format will occur warning or error at compilation time or runtime.

**Function 1** - the `printf()` is the common function to write C strings to the standard output `stdout` (declared in `<stdio.h>`).

> See the [C library function - printf()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm)

```
int printf(const char *format, ...)
```

In the provided source code, the `printf()` function has been used in the following cases:

1. `printf("It work\n");` to write a fixed string which complies with the `const char *` expected format of the first parameter ==> **OK**,
2. `printf(var1);` to write the content of the entered string `var1` (declared as `char var1[100];`) which not exactly complies with `const char *` of the first parameter but will be cast during compile time. A proposed format to write the `var1` string could be `printf("%s",var1);` (or more verbose `printf("var1: %s",var1);`) where the first parameter `"%s"` will specify that the following argument `var1` will be a string.
3. `printf(f);` to write the content of the random value (declared as `char f;`) which doesn't comply with `const char *` of the first parameter and doesn't compile at all. The minimal expected format to write the `f` character is `printf("%c",f);` (or more verbose `printf("f=%c",f);`) where the first parameter `"%c"` will specify that the following argument `f` will be a character.

**Function 2** - the `strcmp()` is a function to compare two C strings parameters (declared in `<string.h>`.

> See the [C library function - strcmp()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm)

```
int strcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2)
```

In the provided source code, the `strcmp()` function has not been used as specified. The function expects two input parameters:

1. First parameter of `strcmp(var1,...)==0` is `var1` (declared as `char var1[100];`) which not exactly complies with `const char *` but will be cast during compile time.
2. Second parameter of `strcmp(...,f)==0` is `f` (declared as `char f;`) which doesn't comply with `const char *` and doesn't compile at all.

> To compare the character `f` with `var1`, it shall be necessary to
>   convert it to a string (In C, a string is an array of `char` ended by
>   a  character).

**Solution 1** - how to convert the character `char f;` to a string.

A C string is an array of characters: `char str_f[]= { '<char>', ... , '<NUL>' };`. Meaning that a minimal array of 2 characters is necessary to convert the character `char f;` to a string.

```
char f = rand() % 38;
// use a 2 characters string
char str_f[2] = { f, '\0' };
// Could be also initialised as str_f[0] = f; str_f[1] = '\0'; 

// compare the strings using `str_f`
if (strcmp(var1,str_f)==0) {
```

**Warning 1** - be careful to the random value range.

> When printing characters, a C string is supposed to be filled by ASCII
>   characters different from  which is used to end the string.

In the provided source code, the assignment of `f`, `char f = rand() % 38;`, will generate values from 0 to 37 which include the  character and the first 31 non-printable characters (ctrl-characters). Only characters greater than 31 will be displayed.

> In will be more easy to generate: `char f = ' ' + (rand() % 38);`
>   where `' '` is the first printable ASCII character `= 32`.

Comment: OP wants `char f` to hold a "randomly generated *number*", not a character.

Comment: @RadLexus, in that case, the `fgets()` function is not the easiest way to enter non-printable `char` to match with the range [0..38[ random number.

Comment: Or the reverse. OP is clearly struggling to see the difference between a `char` *value* and a `char *` a.k.a. "C string".

Comment: @J.Piquard Thanks. I had edited my code. It complied! But I wasn't able to get anything displayed when I print str_f.

Comment: @butbut, You have declared an array of 7 char `char myArray[7];` and you are computing an index in the range of [1..100] `int randomindex= 1 + (rand() % 100);`. So it results of 6% to get a value pointing in the `char myArray[7];` otherwise out of range (often is 0).

Comment: @butbut, you can replace `printf("%s",str_f);` by a more deep display `printf("[%d]=%d, \"%s\"",randomindex,f,str_f);` to better understand what is happening.

Comment: @J.Piquard After replace with `printf("[%d]=%d, \"%s\"",randomindex,f,str_f);` , I can see that `%d` is generating random number and displaying but str_f is not. I don't get it that if f is displaying a value, why str_f not? str_f is just converted from character (f) to a string,Shouldn't it have the same value with f?

Comment: The `f` value is displayed using the specifier `%d` meaning a decimal integer of the value. But when displaying `f` with `%c` (or `str_f` with `%s`), the value will be displayed as a ASCII char. And all listed values (in `{ 0,28,9,26,30,11,7 }`) are non-printable ASCII char. (see my **'Warning 1'** above).

Comment: @J.Piquard If it is non-printable, will it still work in `strcmp()` ? Comparing two strings. Will the comparation part work?

Comment: @butbut, the function `strcmp()` will work with printable or non-printable char excepted the `<NUL>` string terminator (the comparison will stop to the first `'\ 0'` encountered).